# Parsing XML by element in Python using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree

I am trying to use ElementTree in Python to parse through some local XML files and remove all of the elements that do not have a parent tag of "DVC". However, the following code is still letting elements with tags other than "DVC", specifically "PFD" and "CTR", through into my output XML file:

```
exp_root = etree.parse(dm_files_path + "\\Export\\" + display_name + "\\TASKDATA.XML")
root = exp_root.getroot()

for child in root:
    if child.tag !='DVC':
        root.remove(child)

exp_root.write(dm_files_path + "\\Export\\" + display_name + '\\TASKDATA_Disp.XML')
```

Here is an example XML file before running the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TaskData VersionMajor="4" VersionMinor="2" Taskr="" Version="201" DataTransferOrigin="2">
    <TSK A="TSK-1" B="Fi" C="CTR-1" D="FRM-1" E="PFD-1" G="2">
        <TLG A="TLG00000" C="1"/>
        <TIM A="2019-08-22T16:33:39.824+00:00" D="4"/>
        <OTP A="CPC-1"/>
        <DAN A="A00C80000C40B6BC" B="FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF" C="DVC-1">
            <ASP A="2019-08-22T16:33:40" D="4">
                <PTN A="41.7616234560" B="-87.9292605396" D="1"/>
            </ASP>
        </DAN>
    </TSK>
    <PFD A="PFD-1" C="NoField" D="0" E="CTR-1" F="FRM-1"/>
    <FRM A="FRM-1" B="NoFarm" I="CTR-1"/>
    <CTR A="CTR-1" B="NoGrower"/>
    <CPC A="CPC-1" B="SPRAYING"/>
    <DVC A="DVC-1" B="Sprayer" C="02.00.01 " D="A00C80000C40B6BC" E="  30397040 Z12338" F="3037313131464C" G="FF565A005F6E65">
        <DVP A="6001" B="0" C="0.2641719878" D="0" E="gal"/>
        <DVP A="6003" B="0" C="0.0002471050" D="2" E="ac"/>
        <DVP A="6004" B="0" C="0.0000006214" D="2" E="mi"/>
        <DVP A="6005" B="0" C="0.0002777780" D="2" E="hours"/>
        <DVP A="6006" B="0" C="0.0393701009" D="0" E="in"/>
        <DVP A="6008" B="0" C="0.0002641720" D="2" E="gal"/>
        <DVP A="6010" B="0" C="0.0000106907" D="4" E="gal/ac"/>
        <DPT A="4003" B="009D" C="2" D="Connector Type"/>
        <DPT A="4484" B="00B3" C="3" D="Operation Type (ACP)"/>
    </DVC>
<TaskData>
```

Here is the resulting XML file output:

```
<TaskData VersionMajor="4" VersionMinor="2" Taskr="" Version="201" DataTransferOrigin="2">
    <PFD A="PFD-1" C="NoField" D="0" E="CTR-1" F="FRM-1"/>
    <CTR A="CTR-1" B="NoGrower"/>
    <DVC A="DVC-1" B="Sprayer" C="02.00.01 " D="A00C80000C40B6BC" E="  30397040 Z12338" F="3037313131464C" G="FF565A005F6E65">
        <DVP A="6001" B="0" C="0.2641719878" D="0" E="gal"/>
        <DVP A="6003" B="0" C="0.0002471050" D="2" E="ac"/>
        <DVP A="6004" B="0" C="0.0000006214" D="2" E="mi"/>
        <DVP A="6005" B="0" C="0.0002777780" D="2" E="hours"/>
        <DVP A="6006" B="0" C="0.0393701009" D="0" E="in"/>
        <DVP A="6008" B="0" C="0.0002641720" D="2" E="gal"/>
        <DVP A="6010" B="0" C="0.0000106907" D="4" E="gal/ac"/>
        <DPT A="4003" B="009D" C="2" D="Connector Type"/>
        <DPT A="4484" B="00B3" C="3" D="Operation Type (ACP)"/>
    </DVC>
<TaskData>
```

As I mentioned above, I expect  "if child.tag !='DVC': root.remove(child)" to remove all of the elements that do not have "DVC" as their tag. However, as shown in the picture of my output XML file, some elements with tags other than "DVC" are not being removed.

Any help with this issue would be much appreciated. I read through the ElementTree documentation online and I am still confused as to why this is happening.

Thank you!

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your files, that's useless. Post your files, copy&paste.

Comment: Don't add/remove items from a sequence while you're iterating over it.  That way lies madness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot iterate a collection (`child in root`) and change that very collection at the same time, this will always produce unpredictable results.

Copy the items you want work on into a list, and then iterate that list:

```
elems_to_delete = [child for child in root if child.tag != 'DVC']

for elem in elems_to_delete:
    root.remove(elem)
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you for taking the time to answer my question and provide an explanation.

Comment: Good to hear! Could you still replace the screenshots in your question with actual code (so that the question context remains complete even if the links to the screenshots break), that would be perfect.